# Simple form wrong input type on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, simple-form

I have a simple_form that works perfectly in development. Yet when I push to Heroku one attribute's input type changes from checkbox to text.

The attribute is named "Dorm", and it's in the Room model.
So I typed this line in both the Dev and Heroku consoles:

```
Room.columns_hash["dorm"]
```

Here is what I got in each one:

Development:

```
 => #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLiteColumn:0x000000058be6d8 @name="dorm", @sql_type="boolean", @null=true, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @type=:boolean, @default=nil, @primary=false, @coder=nil>
```

Heroku:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x00000005755c10 @name="dorm", @sql_type="boolean", @null=true, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @type=:boolean, @default=nil, @primary=false, @coder=nil>
```

And this is the line i'm using on my form:

```
= f.input :dorm,input_html: {class: 'dorm'}
```

The attribute's sql_type and type are correct in both environments (boolean). Why am I getting a text input in Heroku?

Appreciate all and any help!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the problam was I had run a migration on the server and hadn't restarted the heroku server...
So just:

```
heroku restart -am app_name
```

solved my problem